# PubNub Subscribe_Key Unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, pubnub

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:

https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-07-22-getting-started-with-raspberry-pi-2-and-pubnub-in-python-programming-language/

And I get to the "subscribe_key" part. When I run the script, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/python/send.py", line 5, in <module>
    subscribe_key = "sub-code-from-my-account")
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'subscribe_key'
```

This tutorial seems to be out of date. When I type exactly what they're suggesting in the first couple steps, I still get errors. I searched for what is wrong with the code, and it seems the the syntax is all changed. For example, they suggest this code:

```
from pubnub import Pubnub
```

But it doesn't work. A google search told me that it's recently changed to:

```
from pubnub.pubnub import PubNub
```

And this works fine. But I then get to the subscribe_key line and there's an error. What am I missing?

Comment: Blogs are moments in time and do not get updated. Can you share your code with your keys redacted?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they've made some major changes on version 4 of the sdk and the syntax has changed quite a bit. This is the api reference for version 4 with a getting started guide: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python/pubnub-python-sdk-v4

If you want to follow the blog post you linked to, you can install version 3 of the sdk:

```
pip install 'pubnub>=3,<4'
```

Also the sdk reference for version 3 is here: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python/pubnub-python-sdk

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest PubNub 4 SDK, then you need to do:

```
from pubnub.pnconfiguration import PNConfiguration
from pubnub.pubnub import PubNub

mypubnubconfig = PNConfiguration()

mypubnubconfig.subscribe_key = 'YourSubscribeKeyHere'
mypubnubconfig.publish_key = 'YourPublishKeyHere'

pubnub = PubNub(mypubnubconfig)
```